# Correct find syntax for :first, :order in Rails 3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, find

I am currently using the following to retrieve a town name:

```
place = Town.find(:first, :conditions => ["name = ?", params[:place_post]])
place ||= Town.find(:first, :order => "damlev(`towns`.`name`, '" + params[:place_post] + "')")
```

What would be the best way to do this, named scopes etc I just feel this is well rubbish and bad practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If params[:place_post] is the name of the town:

`place = Town.find(:first, :conditions => ["name = ?", params[:place_post]], :order => "name [ASC|DESC]")`

Use either ASC or DESC.

**Updated** with ARel syntax:

`place = Town.where(:name => params[:place_post]).order("name [ASC|DESC]").first()`

or:

`place = Town.order("name [ASC|DESC]").find_by_name(params[:place_post])`

Don't know exactly what's the idea with the demlev function, but this may work:

`place = Town.order("demlev(name, #{quoted_place_post]}) [ASC|DESC]").find_by_name(params[:place_post])`

quoted_place_post can be Town.quote_value(params[:place_post])

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So this is the correct way then? I have just been seing the use of Town.order().first() in some examples of Rails 3. Just to clarify [:place_post] is the name of the town : )

Comment: Both are equivalent (for the moment), the one with method chaining is using ARel. Apparently the first syntax will be deprecated in Rails 3.1.

Comment: That worked great thanks, I knew there was something. However it does not fully answer my question as I am wondering how to include the params in the levenshtein function and whether this should be a named scope? Also thanks for explaining ARel as I am new to Rails and just trying to learn all the right practices and as you say not the ones that will soon be deprecated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with demlev function... but, for what I know, it usually takes 2 params and maybe you can use it as: demlev(params[:place_post1], params[:place_post2]).

Comment: I will mark this as answered now, thank you for your input changed most of my Finds etc now and will have to work on the order aspect and scopes.